# Extjs add div into a window

Tags: html, extjs, desktop, addition

i would like to add a new div tag by clicking a button, but it doesnt work.
I have a web desktop from extjs and two modules. One window like the following code, with 1 div [20,20]. And a second window with a button and handler to add a new div tag in the first window. But it doesnt work.

```
            win = desktop.createWindow({
            id: 'firstwindow',
            title: 'firstwindow',
            width: 421,
            height: 391,
            divs: [{
                x: 20,
                y: 20
            }],
```

and so on..

and here the code for adding a div in the firstwindow by clicking button in the second window

```
                handler: function(){
                    if (Ext.getCmp('firstwindow')) {

                        Ext.getCmp('firstwindow').add({
                            divs: [{
                                x: 20,
                                y: 40
                            }] 
                        })
                        Ext.getCmp('firstwindow').render();
                        console.log(Ext.getCmp('firstwindow'));
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance,
cheers,
Thomas

Comment: may be you should explain what you are trying to do with the DIVs..

Answer (score 1):

The add method you are using is used to add a ExtJs component into the container (in your case  its Window). You **cannot** create a DIV tag using the add method.

In ExtJS you can create a component and add it to the container. If you need to modify the DOM, you will have to update the el property. By default, in ExtJS its a DIV tag. You can override this by the autoEl config.

A possible solution:

Now, If you want to repeatedly create a DIV tag with some content in it and rendered dynamically, you can take the help of DataView. Create a Template with your DIV and its child.. load data into the store and finally render them or update DataView in your window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use Ext.getCmp('firstwindow').doLayout() instead of Ext.getCmp('firstwindow').render()